# How Can I change the order of TAB? "tabindex" does not work

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I would like to change the order of tab button.
The default order as stated below.

1. Sign in name
2. Forget your password?
3. Password

I want to change as written below.

1. Sign in name
2. Password
3. Forget your password?

I set custom js with reference to https://learn.microsoft.com/ja-jp/azure/active-directory-b2c/javascript-and-page-layout?pivots=b2c-custom-policy.
And I use the HTML template(https://login.microsoftonline.com/static/tenant/templates/AzureBlue/unified.cshtml).

However the order is not changed.
(And I also try to use custom css. I get same result...)

Can I ask how to fix it? or Could you tell me how to change the tab order in other way?

I think custom js is read

[image]

```js
$(function() {
  $("#signInName").wrap(
    '<div id="signInNameContainer" tabindex="1" </div>'
  );
  $("#password").wrap(
    '<div id="passwordContainer" tabindex="2" </div>'
  );
  $("#forgotPassword").wrap(
    '<div id="forgotContainer" tabindex="3"></div>'
  )
});
```

```css
#signInName {
  tabindex="1";
}

#password {
  tabindex="2";
}

#forgotPassword {
  tabindex="3";
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="signInName" placeholder="Sign-in name" />
<input type="password" id="password" placeholder="Password" />
<input type="button" id="forgotPassword" value="Forgot password" />
```

Comment: I made you a snippet. I am not sure I understand the issue. Please update the snippet to a [mcve] with the order that your are describing

Comment: 1) the CSS you've shown is completely invalid, in terms of both syntax and the use of a `tabindex` property, which doesn't exist. 2) The `tabindex` attribute should ideally be placed in the HTML on the `input` or `a` elements - not `div`. I'm not sure why you're using `wrap()` at all...?

Comment: Please look at documentation for tabindex. For example: [MDN docs - HTML - tabindex](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/tabindex). Also please [read the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a good bunch of syntax errors, including totally made up CSS. But even if you fix them, your intention is to navigate the actual form controls, not some wrapping elements. For that, you can use [jQuery.prop()](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) to set the DOM property of the form elements (tweak the order to your liking, I did it this way so there're visible changes in the snippet):

```js
$(function() {
  $("#signInName")
    .wrap('<div id="signInNameContainer"></div>')
    .prop("tabindex", 1);
  $("#password")
    .wrap('<div id="passwordContainer"></div>')
    .prop("tabindex", 3);
  $("#forgotPassword")
    .wrap('<div id="forgotContainer"></div>')
    .prop("tabindex", 2);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="signInName" placeholder="Sign-in name" />
<input type="password" id="password" placeholder="Password" />
<input type="button" id="forgotPassword" value="Forgot password" />
```

Also note that wrapper container is not necessary for this feature (you could just remove the entire `.wrap()` statements). I left that part to showcase how to have both things, in case you need them for e.g. styling.

Comment: While it's debatable whether it *should* be done, applying a `tabindex` to a `div` does allow for tab-navigation in most browsers: https://jsfiddle.net/mx8qf2ju/

Comment: @DBS I stand corrected, thank you for the hint.

Comment: @Álvaro González thank you for your answering. It is really helpful!!